# Passing data from Angular form to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to save form data in Angular by ajax to store.php file. But, seems data is not properly fetched by file. Can someone point the mistakes?

```
<form id="form1" post="content/store.php">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="examplename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examplename" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleemail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleemail" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitting()" >Submit</button>          

</form>
```

ANGULAR SCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller ('myCtrl',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.submitting = function(){

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "localhost/content/store.php",
            data: {
                email: $scope.email,
                pass: $scope.password
            }
        });

        request.success(function (data) {
            alert("Successfully data entered! ");
        });

    }

});
```

STORE.PHP

```
<?php
  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
  @$email = $request->email;
  @$pass = $request->pass;
  echo $email; 
?>
```

Comment: try $_POST instead of file_get_contents("php://input");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have declared the your inputs `ng-model`

i.e.,

```
<input type="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" id="examplename" placeholder="Enter your name">
<input type="password" ng-model="pass" class="form-control" id="exampleemail" placeholder="Enter your email">
```

So, that you can access it by

```
email: $scope.email,
pass: $scope.password
```

**Note :**

If you wish to have the input field as password, then change the `type="password"`

**Or**

If you wish to have the inputs as it is then in your controller just change

`$scope.email` and `$scope.name` But it is always better to declare those fields in the `inputs` i.e., `ng-model="email"` and `ng-model="pass"`

Answer (score 2):

if in your controller you want to use

> email: $scope.email

and

> name: $scope.name

or password, you will need to have ng-model binding in your view like so:

```
<form id="form1" post="content/store.php">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="examplename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examplename" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleemail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleemail" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitting()" >Submit</button>          

</form>
```